# redis WATCH syntax unable to understand

Tags: syntax, redis, command

In redis, I read that WATCH can only take keys as it's params.

But in the below example which i found in a book for Redis 4.0.x

```
WATCH leaderboard element = ZREVRANGEBYSCORE leaderboard +inf -inf WITHSCORES
```

where leaderboard is a sorted set.
Can someone explain what does this syntax mean.

Comment: Seems like the example is mashing the `WATCH` and `ZREVRANGEBYSCORE` commands. If you ran this in Redis, it would treat each value after `WATCH` as a key name.

Comment: Might be a simple formatting issue - there should be a newline where "-" is.